# ViewPager extends over the bottom of the screen

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm new to Android development and I'm facing the following issue.
This is the layout of my main activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"
                app:tabTextColor="@color/selected_text"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"/>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/main_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

For each tab in the ViewPager I have a fragment, and this is the layout of one of them

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
    tools:context=".fragments.Reviews">

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/review_totalRating"
        style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:stepSize=".5"
        android:isIndicator="true"
        android:progressTint="@color/golden"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp" />
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/listView_reviews" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then I populate my ListView with items whose layout is defined in another xml file. My problem is with the ViewPager layout_height: it is now set to match_parent, but the element extends over the bottom of the screen, with the result that the last element of the ListView is covered by the navigation buttons.
This is what I see in the design editor
[ViewPager overflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaHJ8.png)

How can I make the element stop before the navigation buttons?

Answer (score 5):

I faced this issue too. It's because of `AppBarLayout` behavior in `CoordinatorLayout`. By default when you create a project from a template it will set up layout with hiding `Toolbar`. You can run your example and check it - just swipe toolbar up and it will hide and `ViewPager` will move up and then correctly sticks to the bottom of the screen.

It's not a solution for some cases so you can disable this behavior by removing `app:layout_scrollFlags` attribute from your `Toolbar`. After this, the toolbar will become unhideable and the `ViewPager` will calculate own height correctly.

Comment: I too faced the same issue and your suggestion was helpful. Is it that a listview is being used instead of a recyclerview?

Answer (score 1):

I solved using a LinearLayout as the only child of the CoordinatorLayout, so everything else becomes a children of the LinearLayout. It seems to me to be just a simple workaround, not a final solution, but now it works. This is now the layout of my main activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/orange_050"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/orange_050"
                app:tabTextColor="@color/orange_050"/>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/main_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</LinearLayout>
```